# Call optaplanner dlls in c#

Tags: java, c#, optaplanner, ikvm, rostering

I am trying to use optaplanner rostering solution as part of my app but I don't know java so I'm trying to use IKVM to convert classes to dlls and call their methods from my c# application but there are so many files and classes and I don't even know where to start from? which classes/dlls I need to get rostering work? what methods I should call to start rosting app? has anybody successfully done that before managed to use their java code from c# application? thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3):

Before you dive into the complexities, try looking at the KIE Server, which allows you to run OptaPlanner projects outside of your app and communicate with them using REST API the server exposes.

A typical workflow would look like the following:

1. Start the KIE Server
2. Deploy your OptaPlanner application
3. Define a solver inside KIE Server
4. Submit a dataset
5. Query the best solution

See [OptaPlanner REST API](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.1.0.Beta3/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single/#_optaplanner_rest_api) documentation for more details. [KIE Server Integration](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.1.0.Beta3/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single/#_kie_server_integration) chapter of the OptaPlanner Workbench quickstart provides an example of optimizing a CloudBalancing dataset.